Woocommerce pass more than 1 variable to woocommerce_before_calculate_totals
I am trying to pass 2 variables to woocommerce_before_calculate_totals

Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function add_custom_price(), 1 passed in wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 324 and exactly 2 expected

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price', 1000, 2);
function add_custom_price($var1, $var2) {}

Is it possible?

The woocommerce_before_calculate_totals  can  is only take one parameter. More detail is here https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/function/WC_Cart::calculate_totals

Try to better explain what you are trying to achieve in details…
